# How to contact another member of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

Is there any private message system? I found an answer that I do not agree with, but some stupid moderator closed it, making it true by definition, so no one can argue with it. I want to contact an author of that question.

How?

Comment: Why do you think the moderators are stupid? You can always add a comment to questions and to answers. If you do, authors will be notified.

Comment: @PaulGaborit, user19502: 50 rep is required to post comments to all questions and answers. Before that you can only comment on your own posts and answers to your questions.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Excat. I forgot this limit. But get 50 rep is not difficult... starting by not saying that moderators are stupid!

Comment: Judging by tge tone of your argument, I think that 50 points limit is well-thought.

Answer (score 22):

There is no private message system in the Stack Exchange system. This is by design. See [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/170190) for discussion.

On your particular point, there is no way to close an *answer*, only questions may be closed, and usually this is not done by moderators but by a vote of 5 users with 3000 reputation or higher.

Also this is a community of users, so calling anyone stupid only reflects badly on *you*. And the moderators were elected on the basis of both their TeX skills and their commitment to the community. "Stupid" is the last adjective I'd choose to describe them.

As Paul notes in the comments, it's always possible (if you have more than 50 reputation) to comment on an answer, and this will notify the person who provided the answer the next time they are on the site.